# Train and validation loss become constant too soon

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

n_inputs is defined as-

```
n_inputs = X.shape[1]
```

and its value is 25

My model-

```
# define encoder
visible = Input(shape=(n_inputs,))
# encoder level 1

'''
e = Dense(400)(visible)
e = Dropout(0.05)(e)
e = ReLU()(e)

'''

# encoder level 2
e = Dense(300)(visible)
e = Dropout(0.05)(e)
e = ReLU()(e)

# encoder level 3
e = Dense(200)(visible)
e = Dropout(0.05)(e)
e = ReLU()(e)

# encoder level 4
e = Dense(100)(visible)
e = Dropout(0.05)(e)
e = ReLU()(e)

# encoder level 4
e = Dense(50)(visible)
e = Dropout(0.05)(e)
e = ReLU()(e)



# bottleneck
n_bottleneck = n_inputs
bottleneck = Dense(n_bottleneck)(e)


# define decoder, level 1
d = Dense(50)(bottleneck)
d = Dropout(0.05)(d)
d = ReLU()(d)

# define decoder, level 2
d = Dense(100)(bottleneck)
d = Dropout(0.05)(d)
d = ReLU()(d)

# define decoder, level 3
d = Dense(200)(bottleneck)
d = Dropout(0.05)(d)
d = ReLU()(d)

# define decoder, level 4
d = Dense(300)(bottleneck)
d = Dropout(0.05)(d)
d = ReLU()(d)

'''
# define decoder, level 4
d = Dense(400)(bottleneck)
d = Dropout(0.05)(d)
d = ReLU()(d)

'''


# output layer
output = Dense(n_inputs, activation='sigmoid')(d)
# define autoencoder model
model = Model(inputs=visible, outputs=output)
# compile autoencoder model
opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.00001)
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1,patience=10)
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='binary_crossentropy')
# plot the autoencoder
#plot_model(model, 'drive/MyDrive/autoencoder_no_compress.png', show_shapes=True)
# fit the autoencoder model to reconstruct input
history = model.fit(X_train_norm, X_train_norm, epochs=500, batch_size=64, verbose=2, validation_split=0.1,callbacks=[es])
```

My loss graph-

[image]

The train and Validation loss are becoming constant really soon and arent changing too after 20 epochs. Is my model too complex for the data or too simple that it isn't overfitting by increasing epochs too?

I have normalized my data, changed a variety of learning rates, ran it for 500 epochs with callback

Comment: What is `n_inputs`?, what is its value?

Comment: @PrakashDahal added

Comment: The model could just be suffering from data leakage if you think the results are too perfect.

Comment: This model is quite large, and not an encoder/decoder. It's just a large fully-connected network. Have you tried 1 or 2 layers?

Comment: @ubuntu_noob you can try with small layers and then increase the layers and check the difference in accuracy